# Prove there exists a deleted neighborhood U of c

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f : D \to R$ and let $c$ be an accumulation point of $D$.  Suppose that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) > 1$.  Prove that there exists a deleted neighborhood $U$ of $c$ such that $f(x) > 1$ for all $x\in U \cap D$.

Here is my work...

By assumption, we can let $\lim_{x\to c} = L > 1$.
Since $L > 0$, we can construct a deleted neighborhood $V$ of $L$ such that $\forall v\in V$, $v > 0$.

By definition, there exists a deleted neighborhood $u$ of $c$ such that $f(u\cap D)\le V$.

However, if any $f(U\cap D)\le V$, then for every $x\in u\cap D,$ $f(x)\in V$ hence $f(x) > 1$.

Comment: What is $D$? Is it a metric space?

Comment: Yes @Matt Samuel